# downgrading pyobjc from7.3 to previous version on my machine

Tags: python, pynput, pyobjc

I recently updated pyobjc on my mac and am having problems running pynput module.

i used this code to update

> pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyObjC PyObjC-core

Is there a way I can revert back to previously installed version of pyobjc. I dont know what that version is

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --upgrade pyobjc==7.2`